# This MySQL query doesn't use my indexes

Tags: mysql, database

The following query get a lists of computer groups. For each group it sums how many computers have state=1 and how many have state=2

```
SELECT 
  cg.id
  cg.order
  cg.group_mode
  cg.created
  cg.updated
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN c.state = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  ) AS sclr7, 
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN c.state = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  ) AS sclr8, 
FROM 
  computer_group cg 
  LEFT JOIN computer c ON cg.id = c.group_id 
WHERE 
  cg.group_mode <> 3 
GROUP BY 
  cg.id 
ORDER BY 
  cg.order ASC;
```

When i run EXPLAIN on this query, mysql returns: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+--------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys        | key                  | key_len | ref                | rows | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+--------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cg   | ALL  | mode                 | NULL                 | NULL    | NULL               |   33 |   100.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c    | ref  | IDX_39B3258BBE45D62E | IDX_39B3258BBE45D62E | 768     | test.c.id          |   57 |   100.00 |                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+--------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

I have the following indexes:

computer_group table

```
+----------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table          | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+----------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| computer_group |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |          33 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| computer_group |          1 | mode     |            1 | mode        | A         |           3 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| computer_group |          1 | order    |            1 | order       | A         |          33 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+----------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

*(something went wrong with copy/paste the computer_group, it is now fixed)*

computer table

```
+--------------+------------+----------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table        | Non_unique | Key_name             | Seq_in_index | Column_name   | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+--------------+------------+----------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| computer     |          0 | PRIMARY              |            1 | id            | A         |        2611 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| computer     |          1 | IDX_39B3258BBE45D62E |            1 | group_id      | A         |          32 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| computer     |          1 | state                |            1 | state         | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+--------------+------------+----------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

I tried to add various indexes but it seems i cant get to prevent the filesort and the temporary table.

This is driving me nuts. I have spend several days trying to fixing this. Am i doing something wrong or is this not preventable?

Comment: you need indexes in your computer table too, on group_id

Comment: i am sorry, i forgot to add copy/paste the indexes of the computer table.

Comment: Your `computer_group` table has indexes for `compuer_group`.  Could you have indexed the wrong table?  Also, how many rows are in each table? Have you done a table analyze recently?

Comment: Also, how long does it take the query to execute?  You don't have many rows in those tables.  Maybe it's got everything cached in memory and index use doesn't matter?

Comment: Probably a cardinality issue

Comment: can you explain a little bit more why you think it is a cardinality issue? it will help me a lot to determine where to search, thank you

Comment: It means out of your total rows the rows fulfilling the WHERE condition constitute an important percentage so mysql decides its faster to use a table scan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get it to use indexes if you eliminate the outer `group by`:

```
SELECT cg.*, c.sclr7, c.sclr8
FROM computer_group cg JOIN
       (SELECT c.group_id, SUM(c.state = 1) as sclr7, SUM(c.state = 1) on sclr8
        FROM computer c
       ) c
       ON cg.id = c.group_id 
WHERE cg.group_mode <> 3
ORDER BY cg.order ASC;
```

MySQL *might* use an index on `computer_group(order, group_mode)` for the query.
The `join` might actually confuse MySQL.  A surer query is this:

```
SELECT cg.*,
       (SELECT SUM(c.state = 1)
        FROM computer c
        WHERE cg.id = c.group_id 
       ) as sclr7,
       (SELECT SUM(c.state = 2)
        FROM computer c
        WHERE cg.id = c.group_id 
       ) as sclr8
FROM computer_group cg 
     ON cg.id = c.group_id 
WHERE cg.group_mode <> 3
ORDER BY cg.order ASC;
```

You want an index on `computer_group(order, group_mode, id)` and `computer(group_id, state)`.